# C++ ulong to class method pointer and back

Tags: c++, c, casting

I'm using a hash table (source code by Google Inc) to store some method pointers defined as:

```
typedef Object *(Executor::*expression_delegate_t)( vframe_t *, Node * );
```

Where obviously "Executor" is the class.

The function prototype to insert some value to the hash table is:

```
hash_item_t  *ht_insert( hash_table_t *ht, ulong key, ulong data );
```

So basically i'm doing the insert double casting the method pointer:

```
ht_insert( table, ASSIGN, reinterpret_cast<ulong>( (void *)&Executor::onAssign ) );
```

Where `table` is defined as a '`hash_table_t *`' inside the declaration of the Executor class, `ASSIGN` is an unsigned long value, and '`onAssign`' is the method I have to map.

Now, `Executor::onAssign` is stored as an unsigned long value, its address in memory I think, and I need to cast back the ulong to a method pointer. But this code:

```
hash_item_t* item = ht_find( table, ASSIGN );

expression_delegate_t delegate = reinterpret_cast < expression_delegate_t > (item->data);
```

Gives me the following compilation error :

```
src/executor.cpp:45: error: invalid cast from type ‘ulong’ to type ‘Object* (Executor::*)(vframe_t*, Node*)’
```

I'm using GCC v4.4.3 on a x86 GNU/Linux machine.

Any hints?

Comment: Why are you using an untyped C hashtable implementation rather than a properly-typed C++ class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I remember correctly, a *class method* pointer may be larger than a normal function pointer due to implementation details. This would explain why the compiler does not allow this cast – the method pointer wouldn’t fit inside the storage space of a “normal” pointer.

The solution, as I’ve stated above in a comment, is to use a proper C++ hash table implementation that allows arbitrary types via C++ templates.

Comment: I should modify a lot of code to use a template hash table class instead of the C implementation, any solution using this one?

Comment: You could use the STL map class or tr1::unordered_map to avoid having to write your own.

Comment: I tried those classes and trust me, the library i'm using is a LOT faster then them .
I need a very fast key lookup mechanism for this project.

Comment: PS: Anyway, i'll use std::map for now :)

Comment: @Simone: if I remember correctly, Google also has a collections library for C++. Can’t find it now, though.

Comment: Is std::map really faster than tr1::unordered_map?

Comment: @Mark: Depends on what you're doing with it.